# doubts in file system hierarchy?

Tags: bash

explain the difference between /bin and /usr/bin used in Linux?

Answer (score 0):

They're different directories, both can hold `bin`ary files for executing.

Historically the reason for having two, is because you could then keep your essential system binaries in `/bin` on the root file system, and then have a separate partition for `/usr` and put your "user" binaries in there.

This is from an era where disks were smaller, and LVM rarer or non existent - so you might have separate physical drives having different bits of your filesystem. It also wasn't too uncommon for someone to trip over the auxiliary disk pack that had `/usr` on it, causing a system crash!

You would therefore need certain essential commands at `boot` time - like for example, `mount` and `fsck` - these would go in `/bin`.

However as time has passed, and drives have got larger - the distinction between the various `bin` locations has become less relevant. On some systems, you'll see symlinks and crossmounts, others not so much.